# How could I save data to /mnt/vendor/persist/ on Android?

Tags: android, telephony, selinux

I want to save some data under /mnt/vendor/persist/ on Android, but when I add selinux permission, Android's neverallow rules block it(domain is radio).

So how could set selinux to save data under /mnt/vendor/persist/ and pass CTS?

I tried to add selinux like below shows:

```
allow radio mnt_vendor_file:dir {search getattr read write add_name remove_name};
allow radio mnt_vendor_file:file {getattr read write create open unlink};
```

but below error occurred：

```
libsepol.report_failure: neverallow on line 96 of device/qcom/sepolicy/qva/vendor/monaco/system_server.te (or line 101816 of policy.conf) violated by allow radio mnt_vendor_file:file { read write create getattr unlink open };
libsepol.report_failure: neverallow on line 96 of device/qcom/sepolicy/qva/vendor/monaco/system_server.te (or line 101816 of policy.conf) violated by allow radio mnt_vendor_file:dir { read write getattr add_name remove_name search };
libsepol.report_failure: neverallow on line 1378 of system/sepolicy/public/domain.te (or line 14256 of policy.conf) violated by allow radio mnt_vendor_file:dir { read write getattr add_name remove_name search };
libsepol.check_assertions: 3 neverallow failures occurred
Error while expanding policy
```